# Does a Ukrainian citizen with UK visa and Estonian residence need a tourist visa to Spain?

Tags: visas, schengen, ukrainian-citizens

My husband is from Ukraine and I am from Latvia (EU). He has UK permit to stay and work in UK for 5 years. He has an Estonian permit to work there as well, but it will expire next October. We are planning to go to Spain in August and would like to know whether he needs a visa to go there.

Comment: Does your husband have a permit of residence (Estonian ID Card) that says 'Temporary right of residence until...'?

Answer (score 4):

Is his visa valid only in UK and Estonia? I know about some cases, where visas were issued only for specific country, but in most cases, the visa is issued for whole Schengen area. If your husband has visa valid for Schengen area, then he will be able to travel to any country in the area, including Spain.

Answer (score 3):

Estonia is a part of Schengen Area, as he has visa to live and work in Estonia that visa will allow him to visit other states within the area without the need to apply for another visa.

Answer (score 1):

No, he does not Need a visa for Spain, only his passport and Estonian residence permit